# Insert object in array of object javascript

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have two Arrays of Objects:

```
{
"records": [
  {
      "lead_id": 97195,
      "user_id": 613,
      "segment_id": 0,
      "email_address": "asdf@lkasd.asd",
      "full_name": "asdf asdf",
  },
  {
      "lead_id": 97197,
      "user_id": 613,
      "segment_id": 0,
      "email_address": "asdfasdfasdf@asdasdasd.com",
      "full_name": "asdf asdf",
  }
  ]  
}
```

And the second array of objects:

```
  {
       "userTags": [
        {
          "lead_id": 97195,
          "user_tag_id": 93,
          "tag_name": "Julien",
        },
        {
          "lead_id": 97195,
          "user_tag_id": 93,
          "tag_name": "test123"
        },
        {
          "lead_id": 97197,
          "user_tag_id": 93,
          "tag_name": "General Business"
        },
        {
          "lead_id": 97197,
          "user_tag_id": 93,
          "tag_name": "PAREB CLRB"
        }
      ]
    }
```

I want to insert the tagname on specific `lead_id` object, for example in records there's `"lead_id" : 97195` and the userTags `"lead_id" : 97195`, that's my catcher or hint that should be connected on that Array of objects but I dont have any idea how can I insert the `tag_name` object in the `records` list

example output

```
"records": [
  {
      "lead_id": 97195,
      "user_id": 613,
      "segment_id": 0,
      "email_address": "asdf@lkasd.asd",
      "full_name": "asdf asdf",.
      "tag_name": "Julien",
  }]
```

Comment: This is the only expected output ? you have 2 lead_id records and 4 lead_id in userTags

Comment: @GovindParashar Hi actually all that have same lead_id will be join in the records array, I just make it short, sorry man if make it more confusing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using `map` and `find` to iterate over your records and add the `tag_name` field that you find in the `userTags` object.

However, you seem to have multiple `tag_name` for the same `lead_id`.
I have added two example, one that takes the `tag_name` of the first matching `lead_id` and one that collects all `tag_name` for all matching `lead_id`:

```js
const records = {
  "records": [
    { "lead_id": 97195, "user_id": 613, "segment_id": 0, "email_address": "asdf@lkasd.asd", "full_name": "asdf asdf" },
    { "lead_id": 97197, "user_id": 613, "segment_id": 0, "email_address": "asdfasdfasdf@asdasdasd.com", "full_name": "asdf asdf" }
  ]  
};

const userTags = {
  "userTags": [
    { "lead_id": 97195, "user_tag_id": 93, "tag_name": "Julien" },
    { "lead_id": 97195, "user_tag_id": 93, "tag_name": "test123" },
    { "lead_id": 97197, "user_tag_id": 93, "tag_name": "General Business" },
    { "lead_id": 97197, "user_tag_id": 93, "tag_name": "PAREB CLRB" }
  ]
};

const newRecords = {
  records: records.records.map(record => {
    const lead_id = record.lead_id;
    const tag = userTags.userTags.find(tag => tag.lead_id === lead_id);
    return { ...record, tag_name: tag.tag_name };
  })
};

const newRecordsMult = {
  records: records.records.map(record => {
    const lead_id = record.lead_id;
    const tags = userTags.userTags
      .filter(tag => tag.lead_id === lead_id)
      .map(tag => tag.tag_name);
    return { ...record, tag_name: tags };
  })
}

console.log(newRecords, newRecordsMult);
```

Comment: Hi mate thanks for the showing me the solution,I have a question for 
 return { ...record, tag_name: tag.tag_name };

hows that execute ?

Comment: @Mike Victoria, { ...record } will spread the content of record in the new object, it is called the spread operator: [see the doc here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

Answer (score 0):

This is my way… maybe rough but it works :)

```
let main_array = {
    "records": [
        {
            "lead_id": 97195,
            "user_id": 613,
            "segment_id": 0,
            "email_address": "asdf@lkasd.asd",
            "full_name": "asdf asdf",
        },
        {
            "lead_id": 97197,
            "user_id": 613,
            "segment_id": 0,
            "email_address": "asdfasdfasdf@asdasdasd.com",
            "full_name": "asdf asdf",
        }
    ]
}

let tag_array = {
    "userTags": [
        {
            "lead_id": 97195,
            "user_tag_id": 93,
            "tag_name": "Julien",
        },
        {
            "lead_id": 97195,
            "user_tag_id": 93,
            "tag_name": "test123"
        },
        {
            "lead_id": 97197,
            "user_tag_id": 93,
            "tag_name": "General Business"
        },
        {
            "lead_id": 97197,
            "user_tag_id": 93,
            "tag_name": "PAREB CLRB"
        }
    ]
}

//loop main array
main_array["records"].forEach(function(item){
    let lead_id = parseInt(item.lead_id);
    let temp_array = [];

    //loop tags
    tag_array["userTags"].forEach(function(tag){
        if(lead_id === parseInt(tag.lead_id)){
            temp_array.push(tag.tag_name);
        }
    });

    item.tags = temp_array;
});

console.log(main_array);
```